# Bottom bar - every position option causes special issues

Tags: html, css

There is bottom bar on every page.

Now it has CSS:

```
#bottom_nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-color: #f7f7fe;
    background: url('http://localhost:3000/assets/font-try.jpg');
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "ProximaNova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;


}
```

But with `position: absolute;` if document height is more than window height, it just goes above page content.

With `position: relative;` page is rendered wrong if there are some other relative elements.

`position: fixed;` - same result as absolute.

And with usual `margin-top` if document height is small, it can be on the middle of the page.

At the moment I fixed it with JS script, but I'm sure that there is better approach, how usually bottom bars are set?

Comment: If you put up a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net), people can help you better.

Comment: Problem that there are a lot of dynamic pages (Rails app), I can't put everything on jsfiddle, just looking for common approach

Comment: By bottom bar do you mean it stays at bottom of `document` (default position should work fine here, ie, `static`) or bottom of window (`position: fixed` would be best)? I don't know in what case position `relative`/`absolute` would be useful.

Comment: It is always in the bottom on document, not window. But with static, If document height is 300px, it will be in the middle of the page

Comment: Set a `min-height` of your container above the bottom bar so that bottom bar ends up at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML somthing like this:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="bottom_nav"></div>
</div>
```

use this css:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#page {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ff0;
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#bottom_nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}
```

And one simple CSS rule for IE 6 and IE 5.5:

```
#page {
    height:100%;
}
```